# resolve is not passing data from factory to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I am newbie to resolve function in ui-router and i am not getting answer for call to factory whereas i get the value if i just simply pass a string.

I tried console.log  for factory and i am getting an output.

**State Function**

```
  .state('trainer.classes',
     {   url: "/trainer/classes",
          controller:"trainerClassesCntrl",
         templateUrl: "views/trainer/trainer.classes.tpl.html",
         resolve : {courses : function(courseFactory){
                                          courseFactory.get().then(function(response){
                                            // console.log(response); //Getting output
                                          return response;
                                        });
                                        // return  "asdf"; //Getting output as test case.
                                      }
                                    },
         permissions:{allow : ['trainer']}

     })
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('trainerClassesCntrl',['$scope','apiService','$rootScope','courses',function($scope,apiService,$rootScope,courses){
  console.log(courses); // undefined for coursesFactory return and asdf for simple return.

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the promise. Try something like this:

```
.state('trainer.classes', {
    url: "/trainer/classes",
    controller: "trainerClassesCntrl",
    templateUrl: "views/trainer/trainer.classes.tpl.html",
    resolve: {
        courses: function(courseFactory){
            return courseFactory.get();
        }
    },
    permissions: {
        allow: ['trainer']
    }
})
```

You can read more about using resolves with ui-router here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Wonderful.Working now. But couldnt get the point why its not working earlier. your reference has this example  promiseObj2:  function($http){
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'})
               .then (function (data) {
                   return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
               });
         },

Comment: so, using that example, your earlier approach would have looked like this: `promiseObj2: function($http){ $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}) .then (function (data) { return doSomeStuffFirst(data); }); }`. Notice the missing `return` in the outer function.